# Can not change desktop environments

Tags: debian, desktop-environment

I am trying to check out different desktop environments, so I installed Debian 12.4 and included several of the desktop environments during the installation. Immediately after installing, I am using the gnome desktop as shown by the following command:

```
$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
gnome
```

Everything I find on the Internet tells me that I can change my desktop environment with the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

So, I ran that and selected the Cinnamon desktop, and then restarted the system. After I login, nothing about the desktop environment looks any different than before. I don't think the command had any effect at all. The `$DESKTOP_SESSION` environment variable still says gnome, but `update-alternatives` thinks I am using the Cinnamon desktop.

How would I know if the desktop environment really changed or not? I doesn't look like it did. The only different is that the environment variable and the update-alternatives now think I am using different desktops.

How can I actually know which desktop environment is in use, and how can I change from one to another reliably?

Comment: the graphical login screen should have a list of desktop managers to choose from

Comment: I looked there, but saw nothing in Debian 12.4 that would let me choose the desktop at login. Maybe this is just a Debian problem?

Answer (score 0):

The new DE isn't installed correctly.

To install cinnamon, use `sudo tasksel` then select cinnamon or use:

```
sudo apt install task-cinnamon-desktop
```

You are using the right commands to check and switch between the DE.